# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context when querying Identity table database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My project is set up as follows..
MainProject
DataAccess its a Class Library
EntityFramework Database tables its a Class Library
EntityFramework Identity tables its a Class Library

In my main projects webconfig I have 2 connectionstrings, one is for the normal database tables and the other is for the Identity tables. The connectionstring for the normal database tables is an entity framework connectionstring

```
<add name="HWCEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HWCEF.csdl|res://*/HWCEF.ssdl|res://*/HWCEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

The identity entityframework connectionstring is this

```
<add name="HWCIdentityEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HWCIdentityEF.csdl|res://*/HWCIdentityEF.ssdl|res://*/HWCIdentityEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

however if I place that connectionstring in the main project's webconfig, and try to log into the web app, I get this error

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

and its pointing at line 78 of AccountController

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

So instead of using the Identity connectionstring, I use this one

```
<add name="HWCIdentityEntities" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;password=****;Integrated Security=false;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

using that connectionstring doesn't throw any error, and I would be fine with using that connectionstring but when I try and query the Identity database, I get this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException' occurred in HWC.Identity.dll but was not handled in user code 
>   Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

and this error is thrown in my HWCIdentityEF.Context.csdl|res

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

How can I fix this so I can query the Identity database? I am assuming that I need to use the Identity connectionstring in the main application?

Comment: What does your context class look like? What does it inherit from?

Comment: @DavidG, I took the identity tables, left them in its own database and then generated the EF from the database

Comment: You need to show some more code here, also, what is `SignInManager`?

Comment: What other code should I add? Because I am not sure. SignInManager, that's all generated when you create an MVC project

Comment: If the identity tables are in the same database with the app tables, it might be easier to just use a single context that inherits from IdentityDbContext. Then make sure you name the connection string in the context constructor. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316188/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)

Comment: @SteveGreene, I agree with you, but the identity tables are sitting in another database. So I have two databases, the one that holds the normal stuff and then the other holds the identity tables

Comment: @SteveGreene, So I added the identity tables to my other database and made the necessary adjustments and now if I have the ADO connection string in my main projects web config, I can log in, but nothing else will work IE other queries, but if I use the EF connectionstring, I can't login but the queries work

Comment: Are you DB first? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866700/change-asp-net-identity-to-use-existing-database)?

Comment: @SteveGreene, I let MVC create the identity tables, then I wrote the other database myself then combined the two into one... I'll read that link now

Comment: @SteveGreene, originally I was going to have them in a seperate db's but then I needed to have to query the identity tables, and didn't want to use ADO to make calls to that database

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1) Make sure your context looks similar:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("myConnectString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

2) Should be only 1 connect string in web.config

3) Tell Identity to use that context instead of IdentityDbContext. Search for IdentityDbContext and replace it with ApplicationDbContext (or whatever you called it). For example:

A) Startup.cs: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationDbContext>((options, context)=>new ApplicationDbContext());`

B) IndentityConfig.cs (user manager and role manager): `var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));`

```
var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

Comment: My context looks like yours, I only had one IdentityDbContext and it was where my context was (in my IdentityModels).cs. I know I should have one connectionstring in my webconfig, and I do, but depending on which one I uncomment, will determine what I can do. I can either login and none of my queries work, or I can't login and my queries work. I also created a new project and imported controllers and views to it and generated my Entity Framework stuff from my existing database. That project contains 3 projects, The Main, the EF and a DAL. So i combined the identity tables to the other database

Comment: That project also blows up and I get that long drawn out error, with this one..System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException.
If I remove the  throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException(); from the Context.cs then I get a bunch of errors saying I am missing keys

Answer (score 0):

After reading solution after solution, and thanks to Steve Greene, I finally figured out what the issue was. I had to change the name of one of the connectionstrings, and changed its context. Now I can login and my queries run.